# Referencing x86 and x64 DLL in C++/CLI wrapper based on project configuration?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

I do still have an outstanding question that I am not sure of the answer.

When I followed the tutorials to create a C++/CLI wrapper for my DLL I had to add a reference to the DLL to the project:

[image: References]

No problem with that, as such. But here is the thing, the reference path is:

> D:\My Programs\2017\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\x86\Release\MSAToolsLibrary.dll

I actually have two DLL files. One for x86 and one for x64. Can I set up the wrapper project files in such a way that it references the x64 file and x86 file respectively based on the build configuration?

## Update

This is my VCXPROJ file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 [snip]
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MSAToolsLibrary">
      <HintPath>..\..\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\x86\Release\MSAToolsLibrary.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
 [snip]
</Project>
```

I can see a reference to the DLL but I can't see a specific reference for x64 and x86 respectively.

## Update 2

OK, I added the wrapper project into I real solution. x64 is building OK:

[image: x64 1]

[image: x64 2]

But when I set the configuration to x86 I have some problems. There is a small triangle on the references and the errors in the properties:

[image: x86 1]

[image: x86 2]

As you will see from my comment on the existing answer, I am using `$(PlatformTarget)` in the hint. But it seems there is somewhere else we need to adjust references that I can't work out.

## Update 3

OK, If I open the project on it's own in Visual Studio then I can toggle the platforms fine. But when the project is part of my larger project, it does not like it. That is when it fails.

## Update 4

Interestingly, if I am in my master project, and set to the x86 platform, and then in this added project I remove the reference to the DLL and go to add it again (the x86 flavour):

[image: Adding reference]

I do not have this problem in the local solution. It seems like I have to do my development in the local solution and compile there, outside of my master project solution. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `<HintPath>` to be

```
  <HintPath>..\..\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MSAToolsLibrary.dll</HintPath>
```

Comment: Ok, this is the problem I have. Not sure what I can do about it. For x64 it is fine because the `$(Platform)` has a value of `x64`. But where I have `x86` as the folder for the other platform, the DLL Wrapper only lets me use `Win32`. So it is looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: Need `$(PlatformTarget)`

Comment: It is a bit annoying, but it seems that I have no choice but to build the x86 platform by opening up the solution itself. It can't be part of my larger project. x64 can, but not x86.

Comment: Got it ! I did things the other way round. I added all the projects from my master project into the wrapper one instead. I end up with the same projects but I can toggle the platforms and get no errors.